# C# Aumentar ProgressBar en WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, hilos, progressbar

Estoy intentando mostrar el aumento del ProgressBar en un bucle pero directamente cuando aparece se muestra al 100%, no se ve el proceso de aumento.

He probado a poner al final del código un sleep para que cada vez que acaba un elemento del bucle se pare unos segundos para que le de tiempo a mostrarse, pero nada, lo único que hace es que las operaciones que se hacen en el bucle, cuando acaban, tarden dos segundos más, pero la barra no cambia.

```
`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    progressBar.Value = i;
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
}`
```

He visto que se puede hacer con BackgroundWorker o Timer, pero no cuento con esos elementos (si solo se puede hacer con esto y tengo que descargarlo pues un enlace o algo para ello no estaría mal)

Answer (score 0):

mira en mi caso yo lo he hecho asi.

1. necesitas 3 cosas, Un Timer, Una Variable donde lleves el progreso y un Hilo de Ejecucion(Threat)
2. Configuras tu hilo de ejecución para que ejecute el método deseado,ademas, tu timer para que revise el progreso de tu hilo de ejecución y tambien tu progress bar.

aqui el codigo espero que te sirva.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Threading.Thread EjecutaProcesso;
        Timer Timer1 = new Timer();
        int Progreso = 0;

        public void Proceso() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                Progreso += 1;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Configurar progress barr
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            // Configuras timer
            Timer1.Interval = 100;
            Timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
            Timer1.Start();
            //Configuras Hilon e inicia hilo
            EjecutaProcesso = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Proceso));
            EjecutaProcesso.Start();
        }

        void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Progreso <= progressBar1.Maximum)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = Progreso;
            }
            else {
                Timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No puedo crear el Timer como lo has hecho, es decir, me dice que Timer no tiene  ningún constructor que tome 0 argumentos y, por ello, me aparece como error el interval, el tick y el start porque "Timer no tiene una definición para ellos ni un método de extension accesible".

Comment: Es que debes usar el System.Windows.Forms posiblemente tengas un problema de amiguedad, trata de definir el timer asi...  System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

Comment: No me encuentro en Windows Forms, si no que estoy en WPF, por lo que no me lo reconoce.

Comment: pues solo añadelo a las referencias  del proyecto y con eso debe funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo tengo hecho de este modo:

Los botones:

```
<Button Click="OnAuto" Content="Iniciar" />
<Button Click="OnCancel" Content="Cancelar"/>
```

El código:

```
System.Threading.Thread bwt;

private void OnAuto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    worker = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Autofill finalizado!");
}

void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    valueslider.Value = (double)e.ProgressPercentage;
} 

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            bwt = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BackgroundWorkerThread finalizado");
    }
}

private void OnCancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (bwt != null)
    bwt.Abort(); 
}
```

Y listo, tal vez te pida algunos 'using' pero nada fuera de lo habitual.